# Combine data from Case Else on a group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, case

I'm planning to create a group in SQL Server. So with this query I have a result of 2 columns. Columns `Groupings` and `MemberCount`. In such case there's more than one of row `Grp4`. I suppose to must have 4 rows only as result which I don't now how to.

[image]

```
SELECT 
    Groupings = CASE
                  WHEN clnDept = 'Dept1' THEN 'Grp1' 
                  WHEN clnDept IN('Dept2', 'Dept3', 'Dept4') THEN 'Grp2'
                  WHEN clnDept = 'Dept5' THEN 'Grp3'
                  ELSE 'Grp4' 
                END,
    MemberCount = Count(*)
FROM 
    tblEmpData
GROUP BY 
    clnDept
```

How am I going to join or put in 1 row the result grp4 with `CASE ELSE 'Grp4'`? In consideration that I might not know what are the other dept.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some databases, you can use the column alias:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN clnDept = 'Dept1' THEN 'Grp1' 
             WHEN clnDept IN('Dept2', 'Dept3', 'Dept4') THEN 'Grp2'
             WHEN clnDept = 'Dept5' THEN 'Grp3'
             ELSE 'Grp4'
        END) as Groupings,
       Count(*) as MemberCount
FROM tblEmpData
GROUP BY Groupings;
```

Or, repeat the `case` expression:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN clnDept = 'Dept1' THEN 'Grp1' 
             WHEN clnDept IN('Dept2', 'Dept3', 'Dept4') THEN 'Grp2'
             WHEN clnDept = 'Dept5' THEN 'Grp3'
             ELSE 'Grp4'
        END) as Groupings,
       Count(*) as MemberCount
FROM tblEmpData
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN clnDept = 'Dept1' THEN 'Grp1' 
               WHEN clnDept IN('Dept2', 'Dept3', 'Dept4') THEN 'Grp2'
               WHEN clnDept = 'Dept5' THEN 'Grp3'
               ELSE 'Grp4'
          END);
```

Comment: query one got an error column don't exist while query2 works fine with me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
WITH t as (    
  SELECT 
  Groupings = CASE
        WHEN clnDept = 'Dept1' THEN 'Grp1' 
        WHEN clnDept IN('Dept2', 'Dept3', 'Dept4') THEN 'Grp2'
        WHEN clnDept = 'Dept5' THEN 'Grp3'
        ELSE 'Grp4' END,
  MemberCount = Count(*)
  FROM tblEmpData
  GROUP BY clnDept
)
SELECT Groupings, SUM(MemberCount) FROM t
GROUP BY Groupings
```